# Paste code into a discussion?

Tags: formatting, markup

I have a discussion going on our Sharepoint site and I'm trying to paste some JSON for evaluation.  I see no [pre] markup or anything similar.  Am I just missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so you can just use the HTML pre tag even though it's not listed in the formatting guide.